# underscore template: lookup a variable by name

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js, underscore.js, marionette

I'm looking for a way to lookup the value of a variable passed into an underscore template, using a string that contains the variable name. For example, suppose my template contains the following:

```
<% _.each(detailFields, function(fieldName) { %>
    <% print(getValueByName(fieldName)); %>
<% } %>
```

getValueByName() is the function I'm looking for. According to underscore documentation, the values passed to _.template() are put into local scope using a 'with' statement. If I understand correctly, that means window[fieldName] or this[fieldName] won't work. eval(fieldName) is an option, but I'd rather avoid using eval().

Answer (score 0):

Thanks mu, sometimes I miss the obvious. :) I thought Backbone.Marionette was only passing in the attributes of the model. I didn't realize it was passing in the whole model as well, and it was even conveniently named "model". model.attributes[fieldName] solved my issue.